# Crystal reports error Unable to cast COM object of type 'ReportSourceClass' to interface type 'ISCRReportSource'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm using VS2019 with Crystal Reports version 13.0.3500.0. When I'm trying to create a pdf on production machine i get the following error *"Error message: Unable to cast COM object of type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' to interface type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ISCRReportSource'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID"*.

I opened my project on VS2015, convert Crystal Reports to 13.0.2000.0 and everything works fine on production machine.

I added to app.config the following lines based on this article but I still get the same error: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

```
    <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>    
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Web" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonControls" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommonObjectModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CubeDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>    
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ObjectFactory" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Prompting" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="13.0.2000.0" newVersion="13.0.3500.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>  
</runtime>
```

Is there a solution for this error without going back to VS2015? I can't update CR on production machine, because I might have errors on the other applications running with CR 13.0.2000.0 version.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded CR. I remove the old and troubled reference and add the new one.
Also I changed my newVersion to the new one or to what you using.
newVersion="13.0.4000.0" --> you can see this version number on reference list or poperties.